# Proper syntax for reading a CSV using Apache Flink (Scala)

Tags: scala, apache-flink

I need to read a CSV file that has 6 columns, of type Integer, String, String, String, Integer, Integer, respectively. I would like to use Apache Flinks' `ExecutionEnvironment.readCsvFile` method, but I keep getting typing and argument errors. I currently have:

```
val env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
val lines = env.readCsvFile[Integer, String, String, String, Integer, Integer]("C:/Users/zoldham/IdeaProjects/flinkpoc/Data/gun-violence-data_01-2013_03-2018.csv")
```

And get

```
Error:(43, 32) wrong number of type parameters for method readCsvFile: [T](filePath: String, lineDelimiter: String, fieldDelimiter: String, quoteCharacter: Character, ignoreFirstLine: Boolean, ignoreComments: String, lenient: Boolean, includedFields: Array[Int], pojoFields: Array[String])(implicit evidence$1: scala.reflect.ClassTag[T], implicit evidence$2: org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.TypeInformation[T])org.apache.flink.api.scala.DataSet[T]
```

Note that these are lines 42 and 43. What would the proper syntax look like? I have been unable to find any examples to use as a baseline for what it should look like. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a tuple or a case class as input type. Try the following:

```scala
val env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
val lines = env.readCsvFile[(Integer, String, String, String, Integer, Integer)]("C:/Users/zoldham/IdeaProjects/flinkpoc/Data/gun-violence-data_01-2013_03-2018.csv")
```

Comment: I am still getting an error. It now says:

`Error:(43, 85) could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.TypeInformation[(Integer, String, String, String, Integer, Integer)]`

And also that there are not enough arguments for the method readCsvFile

Comment: Did you add `import org.apache.flink.api.scala._`?

Comment: I did. I was actually able to resolve the issue and use the syntax you suggested by adding `import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala._`